# Can I check the value of a dynamic resource in a datatrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, datatrigger

I am wanting to switch a controls style based on the value of a dynamic resource.

```
<Image x:Name="leftImg" Stretch="Fill" Style="{StaticResource BookendImageStyle}" >
    <Image.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{DynamicResource BlackAndWhite}" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="leftImg" Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource BookendImageStyleBW}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Image.Triggers>
</Image>
```

This compiles fine but then at runtime I get the following exception:

```
A 'DynamicResourceExtension' cannot be set on the 'Binding' property of type 'DataTrigger'. A 'DynamicResourceExtension' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.
```

Is what Im trying to do possible? Do I just have the wrong syntax? Should I be doing it a different way?

*EDIT*
I have changed my code to:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ViasTemplate">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Border Padding="{Binding ElementName=templateTest, Path=DataContext.GridRow.LeftBondIndent}" Width="50">
                            <Image x:Name="leftImg" Stretch="Fill" Style="{StaticResource BookendImageStyle}" >
                                <Image.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={StaticResource BlackAndWhite}}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="leftImg" Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource BookendImageStyleBW}" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Image.Triggers>
                            </Image>
```

but now get this exception:

```
Triggers collection members must be of type EventTrigger
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
  <Image x:Name="leftImg" Stretch="Fill" Style="{StaticResource BookendImageStyle}" >
        <Image.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={DynamicResource BlackAndWhite}}" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="leftImg" Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource BookendImageStyleBW}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Image.Triggers>
    </Image>
```

ofcourse you should move this trigger to the image style. DataTrigger can be defined only in style or template

Comment: When trying this I get the same problem. Ive changed it to a static resource now but am now getting a different exception. Please see edited question

Comment: thats what i said, you cant define DataTrigger this way. you should put it in BookendImageStyle or create a new one here and based it on BookendImageStyle

Comment: how would you do this triggering?